# Is it Comic Book or Comics Book?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, variants

Which one is proper `Comic` Book or `Comics` Book? Are both of them grammatically correct? If so, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Comic books" is much more widely accepted than "Comics books." See [Google NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comics+books%2C+comic+books&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

"Comic books" is the more grammatically correct phrase, as "comic" describes the kind of book. A similar example would be "car magazine" versus "cars magazine." Even though the magazines each contain multiple cars, the magazine would be describe with the singular "car."

Comment: You could probably have been a bit more emphatic: "comics book" is nowhere near a "proper" expression with respect to the normal meaning of the term.